# SQl - ORA-00933 error

Tags: java

My code is:

```
try {
    VenLabServComImp.initializepool();
    con = pool.getConnection();
    psmt = con.prepareStatement("select b.category_code,a.category_name " +
            "from IMAGING_SERVICE a ,OS_LABSERVICES_CATEGORY b" +
            "where a.category_code=b.category_code and b.USER_ID= ? and " +
            "b.hosp_id= ? and b.service_id= ? ");

    psmt.setInt(1, servProvId); 
    psmt.setInt(2, HospId);
    psmt.setInt(3, servId);
    rs   = psmt.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()){

        listoutTstIdBean.setCatCode(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("category_code")));
        listoutTstIdBean.setCatNam(rs.getString("category_name"));      
    }
    rs.close();
    psmt.close();
    con.close();    
} catch (Exception excep){
    excep.printStackTrace();
}
```

I got the error that is

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:289)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.Oall7.receive(Oall7.java:582)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.doOall7(TTC7Protocol.java:1986)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.parseExecuteDescribe(TTC7Protocol.java
```

how resolve this?

Comment: [ORA-00933](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00933_sql_command_ended.htm)

Comment: If you print out the sql string, you will see a space missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must add a space between b (before ") and where

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
"from IMAGING_SERVICE a ,OS_LABSERVICES_CATEGORY b" +
```

to

```
"from IMAGING_SERVICE a ,OS_LABSERVICES_CATEGORY b " +
```

a space is missing in your query thats why this exception

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes in when you try to execute an SQL statement with an inappropriate clause.

Try to see the constructed SQL statement and see if there is something wrong. You can use....

```
System.out.println( "DEBUG: query: " + psmt.toString() );
```

before you execute the query to see if the SQL is formed with out any problem.